# Asterisk dial command return dialed number

Tags: variables, asterisk, sip

I'm looking for a variable that can tell me which number 'won' the call on a multi-target Dial command.

Example:

Dial(SIP/1000&SIP/1001&SIP/1002,30)

Set(the_unlucky_winner=${...})

I'm not getting anything from the ${DIALEDPEERx} variables. Sounds like these vars are broken but I don't know if this is what I should be using.

Ancient version 1.2.14 deployed at this site. All clients are SIP

Thanks anyone

Answer (score 0):

Only realistic way do that - cal via Local channle like freepbx do(check freepbx.org source) or use Macro on answer(i am afraid not work in 1.2)

Answer (score 0):

Parse the contents of the CDR record for the file.  One of the fields is `dstchannel` which will hold a value like `SIP/1002-9786b0b0`.

Also keep in mind that the call variable stack is wiped on hangup, unless you have an "`h`" (hangup) extension defined for the context.  So, you can most easily handle your post-call processing there.

**Further Reading:**

1. http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/asterisk-SysAdmin-SECT-1.html

**Please Note:**

*if this answer turns out to solve your problem, please "accept" it for the benefit of others trying to solve the same problem later*

Answer (score 0):

Hi all I have a solution to this problem. It is working fine for both normal dial and multi target dial.

In dialstring add a macro, here I am adding "followme" macro.

```
M(followme)

$agi->exec("dial", "SIP/6001@sip.example.com&SIP/6002@sip.example.com,rtTgM(followme)");
```

Then after call is answered it ll go to context

```
[macro-followme]
```

In this context you write one script to get the connected calls information by

```
$dstchannel=$agi->get_variable("DIALEDPEERNUMBER");
```

Answer (score 0):

**The way I managed to do it is as follows**

```
Dial(SIP/1000&SIP/1001&SIP/1002,30,M(whoanswered))

[macro-whoanswered]
exten => s,1,NoOp(${CHANNEL})
```

You will see that the actual extension that answered is containes in ${CHANNEL}
If 1001 answered the channel will be something like SIP/1001-00017cf1
Just use the CUT command to cut it by **/** and **-**

Comment: Thanks. In the end I avoided the multi-target dial. I preselect my target with bash scripts and dial the right operator from the start.